# JS loading script error

Tags: javascript

I load external scripts to my site with this code:

```
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 script.src = 'http://example.com/script.js';
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

It works, but how to check, if it was an error at the loading? For example timeout, or a server error.

Comment: In case you are open to using jQuery you can use `.getScript` which has built-in error and success handling: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously[link]

Answer (score 9):

You can use the script.onerror to do something when there is an error loading it.

```
script.onerror = function() {
   alert("cannot load script");
}

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Make sure you do it before you attach the script to the document

Comment: You will need to declare the onerror handler before you attach it to the document. Updated my answer to reflect the same

Answer (score 3):

You can set `onload` (and possibly `onerror` - I've only used `onload` myself) on the `script` object before appending it to the document. The event will fire when the script loads successfully (or not, for `onerror`).

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kBkmr/)

```
//check if script was loaded
script.onload = function() {
    alert('loaded');
}

//check if it didn't load
script.onerror = function() {
    alert('foo!');
}
```

Comment: Demo doesn't work when downloading nonexisten script from a valid address - e.g. script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/authNONEXISTENT.js'
Only loaded is fired then.

Answer (score -1):

If you own the script you're referring to, get it to call a function in the calling page to say its ready.  Alternatively you could check for existence of some object that's declared in that script you're loading.