# Load javascript sequentially from javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript widget that is included in a page by inserting a single script tag (as the application should be easiliy distributable):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="loadMyWidget.js"></script>
```

loadMyWidget.js then needs to load multiple script files, which has to run in a certain sequence. I've tried to load them async by inserting script elements into the DOM, but that doesn't give me control of the sequence.

I also tried using head.js which is great for modern browsers, but I can't get it to work in IE7 and 8.

Minifying the scripts into one file is unfortunately difficult, as it is composed of a number of files from different projects and I wouldn't know when to update the script.

As simple as it seems, I need to load javascript files from javascript code in a certain sequence and get it to work in all browsers, including IE7 and 8.

Comment: Have you tried [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)?

Comment: I've considered RequireJS, but I was hoping for a more simple solution.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? In that case you can try nesting `$.getScript()`.

Comment: I'm trying to load jQuery, so that won't help me much :P Thanks, though.

Comment: You could merge jquery into yourloadMyWidget.js.  This would allow you to have your dependencies in your main js file.

Comment: What's the end goal here?  Are you trying to have just one script call and have that single script load the other scripts?  Or is there some other reason for the async loading?

Comment: See my edit. I need to application to be easily distributable, and it is further composed of files from multiple projects.

Comment: One script to rule them all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run into this exact same issue and handled it with:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="other1.js"></script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="other2.js"></script>');

runSomeCode();
```

The code will be loaded and run synchronously. Pros: simple, light, cross browser compliant, no deps. Cons: ugly.

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292763/235179

Comment: I know what you mean. Glad to help.

Comment: Unless I didn't understand right, this overwrites the whole document. So everything that was previously created in the DOM is lost.

Comment: @Neptilo:  You didn't understand right.  Nothing is lost.  `document.write()` adds to the existing document.

Comment: This was so long ago. I don't remember why I thought it would overwrite the whole document. Looking back at my project, I think I ended up solving the issue by not executing any code in the included scripts, but only declaring classes and functions, and then only calling a "main" function from one of these scripts.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using jQuery.getScript() you can use it as a $.when() to hold off execution until things have stopped loading.

If by "sequential execution" you mean that you need to load the requisites before execution the following will work

```
$(function(){
   $.when(
      $.getScript("/script1"),
      $.getScript("/scirpt2"),
      $.getScript("/script3")
}).done(function(){
    // do stuff with the contents of my new script files
});
```

If by sequential execution you mean that you need to execute files one after the other try this:

```
$.Deferred()
.then(function () { return $.getScript("/script1"); })
.then(function () { return $.getScript("/scirpt2"); })
.then(function () { return $.getScript("/script3"); })
.resolve();
```

Of course, this requires jQuery, which after your edits, this may not work for you.

Suggested Reading

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript
- http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: This does not guarantee sequential execution order, does it?

Comment: No, I suppose not.  I understood it slightly differently on first reading.  Working on the edit...

Comment: Looks like a decent solution, if you're using jquery, that is :) +1

Comment: I'll admit, jquery's spoiled me.  I don't do anything without it.

Answer (score 6):

If you need vanilla JS, something like this could work:

```
function loadScripts(scripts, complete) {
    var loadScript = function( src ) {
        var xmlhttp, next;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            try {
                 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                return;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
                next = scripts.shift();
                if ( next ) {
                    loadScript(next);
                } else if ( typeof complete == 'function' ) {
                    complete();
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", src , true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    };

    loadScript( scripts.shift() );
}

loadScripts(['jquery.js','jquery.plugin.js'], function() {
    console.log('loaded');
});
```

Tested in Chrome, should work in IE too.

Comment: This looks great. I figure this is how most of the AMD frameworks work internally. However, I can't get it to work in IE, and the behaviour is quite similar to my attempt with head.js.

Comment: What is not working in IE? (upgrading my VMware, will check in a minute).

Comment: Just tried it in my IE9 with dev tools for IE7-8 versions and it passed my tests. What IE version are you having problems with?

Comment: I'm also using IE9 dev tools. I get a error of an undefined variable, so I guess it's something about the sequence. I got it working with document.write, though I hate that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried require.js? http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadScript(arrayOfUrlStrings, callback) {
  var numScripts = arrayOfUrlStrings.length;
  var count = 0;
  var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]

  function onLoad() {
    count += 1;

    if (count === numScripts) {
      callback();
    } else {
      addScript();
    }
  }

  function addScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = arrayOfUrlStrings[count];
    script.onload = onLoad;
    headElement.appendChild(script);
  }

  addScript();
}
```

Comment: If one script failed to load, all script after that will not be load.