# Load external JS and run a script right after synchronously

Tags: javascript

I have this index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
    <script>
      alert("2");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this index.js:

```
alert("1");
```

How come `alert('2')` is apearing before `alert('1')`.
As far as I know, loading `src/index.js` should be a blocking operation.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kww2o7rm0v

Thanks

Comment: like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10835238/6052427

Answer (score -1):

You could use the SetTimeout() function to make the second alert begin, or, call a function in the other script when the alert is exited, using:

```
alert("1");
// You could either put all of the other script in a function and call that here, or change the src of the script
document.GetElementById("ScriptID").src = "src/index.js";
```

Hope I could help!

Answer (score -1):

Inserting a script element into the document can be accompanied by an `onload` callback function to ensure a sequential process. See Mozilla published docs under Web/API/HTMLScriptElement There are explanations and examples there.