# Why has this script tag been split before being used in document.write()?

Tags: javascript, eval

I've been reading a bit about injecting a script into an HTML file, mostly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously)

But I also came across this variation of using the `document.write` method.

`document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="' + url + '"></scr'+'ipt>');`

What could the advantage be to splitting the `<script` part of the `<script>` tag up like `<scr'+'ipt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any. It is just cargo-culting.

There are problems with having the sequence `</script>` as data inside a `<script>` element (since it will act as an end tag and terminate that script element). That, however, is best  dealt with by an escape rather then a concatenation: `"<\/script>"`. (Best is slightly subjective, but it is shorter, uses fewer operations and is (IMO) more readable).

The concatenation is a valid alternative to it, and some people have misunderstood the need and applied it to start tags as well as end tags, and then other people have just copy/pasted the results. Hence: [cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).