# Javascript trigger if statements if button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have this little javascript code:

```
<script>
        function editHouse()
        {
            if (edit == false) {
                document.getElementById('edit').style.color='red';
                edit = true;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('edit').style.color='blue';
                edit = false;
            }
        }
</script>
    <button id="edit" onclick="editHouse()" type="button">@@@@</button>
```

Which changes the button text to red and blue everytime the button is pressed. However I need more than that, I need other content on the page to enable after the button has been pressed. An example could be enabling some javascript codes like this:

```
if (edit == false) {
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/modalpopup.js"></script>
    }
```

or even enabling whole chunk of codes, maybe including php database connections etc. Is there a way to do that? if I could just write something like:

```
<script>
    if (edit == false) {
</script>
             <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
             <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/modalpopup.js"></script>
<script>
   }
</script>
```

But that wasn't the correct way of doing it unfortunatly. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That won't work. You need to add the script blocks with JS. And if you want DB connections with a mouseclick, you need AJAX.

Comment: Why do you need to do *that*? Try to work things around instead, and you'll come up with a solution that doesn't go against the language's grammar

Comment: How can I add the script blocks with JS? Like a string?

Comment: @Reger it was just an example of what I needed to do to make it easier to understand, I don't know how that would be possible. hmm

Comment: @user3287771 Ok, I understand your point. I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create script element using javascript , refer to this answer : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248500/3323351