# Error when including AngularJS library with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am loading the angular library and checking if the library isn't already included in the script.

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        {{1+1}}
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var angular;
    // load angular library if undefined
    if (typeof window.angular === 'undefined') {

        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        script_tag.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js";

        document.body.appendChild(script_tag);
        console.log(script_tag, 'angular load');

    } else {
        console.log('script found');
    }

</script>
//load angular script
<script type="text/javascript" src="widget-angular.js"></script>
</body>
```

And in the widget-angular.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp', []);
```

The error I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'module' of undefined

First I thought that the cause of the error was because the angular library loaded after the widget script. But I have done various checks and it loads in good order. I have no idea why it doesn't recognise 'module'.
If I call the library directly like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

It works. But the result I need is that it checks if the library is already included. If not, than include the library script.

Thank you advance.

Comment: I don't think that Angular is loaded when you get to that call.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously

Comment: the widget is definitely loading first. You're misinterpreting what the console is telling you.

Comment: Why is this check needed? Usually checks like this go the other way, first statically requesting from googleapis, then checking if it loaded properly, if it didn't, then loading from local. you seem to be doing the opposite. Looks like unnecessary complexity to me.

Comment: I am doing this because it is a widget that I want to be able to use on various websites. 
If one of those websites already has AngularJS library loaded, I don't want to load it again.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to `body` which would place it after your other script tag. Therefore it won't be compiled until after you attempt to access `angular`.

Could use `document.write()` or `document.head.appendChild(script_tag)`.

It should be easy to verify this by inspecting live html in browser console/developer tools

Comment: The order in which it shows in the console is first the angular library and than the widget-angular.js.
If I console.log(script_tag); I see 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>` which is good. But it still shows the error

Comment: that doesn't really make sense due to defintiion of `append`