# JQuery UI dialog not working correctly; error message "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I am trying to make a popup dialog window using JQuery UI and it opens when I click a bookmark button.

When I click first time on the button I get this error and nothing appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)
```

The second time I click, the window appears.
If I click again, The window appears without the title and the text from the body of the window appears at the end of the picture.

This is the code:

```
var script1 = document.createElement('script');
script1.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
var script2 = document.createElement('script');
script2.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js';

document.head.appendChild(script1);
document.head.appendChild(script2);
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>");
$("body").append("<div id='dialog' title='Basic dialog'><p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. </p></div>");

$(document).ready($("#dialog").dialog());
```

Comment: Also to note in addition to @epascarello's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously so perhaps you can include the scripts either as tags in the original HTML or set an `onload` to make sure the code is only executed when jQuery has loaded.  Also is there a specific reason you are loading 2 separate versions of jQiery?  The latest one should be fine unless you have a specific plugin that depends on the earlier version.  Also include the other `append` calls in this `onload` callback as otherwise they are liable to fail and cause errors too.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready($("#dialog").dialog());
```

is not right, you are assigning what is returned from dialog to the ready, not calling it on ready.

```
$(document).ready( function(){ $("#dialog").dialog() });
```

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
$.noConflict(true);
.....
});`

This **$.noConflict(true);** helps me to fix the issue.