# Stop/Hide JS script on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 video scripts:

```
<!--start videoapp-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com/vajs?vid1"></script>
<!--end videoapp-->

<!--start videoapp-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com/vajs?vid2"></script>
<!--end videoapp-->

<!--start videoapp-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com/vajs?vid3"></script>
<!--end videoapp-->
```

I want the first script/video (vid1) to trigger onload.

I want script script/video (vid2) to trigger on click (& to hide vid1):

```
<a id="mylink" href="#">test</a>
```

I want script script/video (vid3) to trigger on click (& to hide vid2):

```
<a id="mylink2" href="#">test</a>
```

I have written this so far, but not sure how to stop/hide the previous videos:

```
<a id="mylink" href="#">test</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');

    myLink.onclick = function(){

        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://test.com/vajs?vid2"; 
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Once a script has been executed and loaded into memory, removing the script tag does nothing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [document.createElement("script") synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously)

Comment: likely need a more robust video API. Without knowing what is in those scripts not much anyone can tell you

Comment: an example video is: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://webvideoapp.com/vajs?a945qPXCjSU6Gsrd2uM4"></script>`