# Create div in javascript file, script part doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I was having the following div in my HTML page:

```
<div  id="jsmolwindow">
<script type="text/javascript">jmolApplet0 = Jmol.getApplet("jmolApplet0", Info);
</script>
</div>
```

I would like to create this div at an appropriate moment in one of my external javascript function.

```
I tried it this way:
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.position="absolute";
div.style.float="left";
div.style.top="200px";
div.style.left = "200px";
div.style.width = "150px";
div.style.height = "150px";
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.type = 'text/javascript';
scr.src = 'jmolApplet0 = Jmol.getApplet("jmolApplet0", Info);'
div.appendChild(scr);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Nothing happens.
I tried to replace scr.src by scr.text but then it tried to execute my script in a new page and failed....

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Why append a `script` element with inline code when you're *already* running JavaScript code? Just execute the statement (probably after appending the `div`).

Comment: have a look here, apparently you cannot add a dynamic js -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously

Comment: @SimoneRiboldi: Yes, you can. That question and answer is about synchronously executing an **external** script.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues there:

1. There's no reason to append a `script` element with inline code when you're *already* running JavaScript code: Just execute the statement right there in your code (probably after appending the `div`).
2. If you really want to append the script element, even though it's not necessary, you set the *content* of the element to the code to run, not the `src` property. The `src` property is a URL of an external script file. You set the content by creating a text node containing the code and appending it to the script element, prior to adding the script element to the document.

But again, #2 is unnecessary and pointless given the code you've shown; just execute the statement.

Comment: I see your point. I was trying to stick as much as possible to the actual code (since I am a beginner) and did not see the obvious. Neither the less I still have two issues when executing directly the javascript in my js file: 1) In my html file I am loading a load of js source to execute this script: "<script type="text/javascript" src="jsmol/js/JSmolCore.js"></script>" .... how to I proceed now? 2) This script is kind of loading a image and I wanted it in that specific div. Hoe do I do? Thanks

Comment: @Laetis: That's a completely different question, and I'm afraid I don't have time to answer it right now. I suggest posting it as a new question, as it's not the same as this one.