# How to know once a dynamically added script is parsed/loaded/executed?

Tags: javascript, onload

I am trying to dynamically load a JavaScript file and, once it is loaded, run a function that is inside the file.  In my main HTML, I basically have:

```
function load_javascript(js_file)
{
    function load_js_callback(example)
    {
        console.log("function " + function_in_js_file + " is " + typeof(function_name));
        if (typeof(function_in_js_file) == "undefined")
        {
            window.setTimeout(load_js_callback(example), 500);
            return false;
        }
        function_in_js_file(example);
    }

    var jstag = document.createElement("script");
    document.head.appendChild(jstag);

    // Browsers:
    jstag.onload=load_js_callback("example");
    // Internet Explorer:
    jstag.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
            load_js_callback("example");
        }
    }
    jstag.setAttribute('src',js_file);
}

load_javascript("/js/example.js");
```

From what I can find on the internet (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248500 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16231055) this should work, but the `jstag.onload` runs before the `function_in_js_file` is defined, so I need the `window.setTimeout` to check again until the function is defined.

Ideally, I would like to get rid of that timeout.  Is there any way to know when the file has been completed loaded/parsed/executed (I'm not sure which is the right term) and the function is defined, ideally without changing the dynamic file?  I have also tried putting the `document.head.appendChild(jstag);` after the `jstag.setAttribute`, but with the same results.

Comment: if you don't use a script require framework that does it for you, i know no js method to be sure your code has been executed. When i tried to do little custom solutions, i ended up with a var at the end of the file (for example named same as the file, or with prefix/suffix). I then test the existence of this var to assure all is executed

Comment: That would basically require a timeout like I have done if the var does not exist?

Comment: yes, or a setInterval rather. I should look at how browserify handles imports, and if there are checks like this.. i'm interested in the matter, i'll update if i find something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's running before the script loads is because:

```
var jstag = document.createElement("script");
document.head.appendChild(jstag);

// Browsers:
jstag.onload=load_js_callback("example");
```

Is assigning the return value of `load_js_callback` to `jstag.onload`. The `onload` handler wants a function:

```
var jstag = document.createElement("script");
document.head.appendChild(jstag);

// Browsers:
jstag.onload=function() { load_js_callback("example"); };
```

As pointed out in the other comments, all this guarantees is that the browser has downloaded the script.

Comment: This definitely looks like the answer, thank you for pointing that out about assigning the return value!  However +Kaddath raises a question as to whether this will wait for the code to be executed, especially with larger files, or will run as soon as it is downloaded as you mention.  I haven't found any documentation on this yet.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer for now.  Hopefully someone will come up with the answer we are looking for - do browsers wait for execution of an appended script before calling onload, but for now this seems to solve the problem.  Thank you!  :)

Answer (score 0):

try this define a function called

```
function loadScript(sScriptSrc, oCallback) {
    var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var oScript = document.createElement('script');
    oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    oScript.src = sScriptSrc;
    // most browsers
    oScript.onload = oCallback;
    // IE 6 & 7
    oScript.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
            oCallback();
        }
    }
    oHead.appendChild(oScript);
}
```

and then call your script file and function inside it via callback

```
    loadScript("/js/example.js", function () {
                //call function
function_in_js_file(example);
            });
```

Comment: you are doing nothing more than him, with this method, js is guaranteed to be loaded, but you cannot be sure that it has been executed

Comment: +Kaddath, thank you!  That was what I was thinking.  So the term I am looking for is executed ?

Comment: Have you tried the solution? Reason it will load and include the file at this time and anything written inside will be executed after including/loading/executing the fike.

Comment: @LalitSachdeva i tried in the past already. This solution works perfectly with little files. But when the code imported is very long and you try to use things without waiting, things can get undefined. Note that this is valid mostly with dynamic imports. Usually, when the html page is parsed traditionnally, you don't have this problem

Comment: After reading +Adam Kewley's answer, I realise this is not exactly the same as mine since this is assigning a function to the onload and my code is actually assigning the output of my `load_js_callback` function, either `false` or `undefined`.  So I'm still not sure whether onload will in fact wait until executed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) js event

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoader', function () {
    load_javascript("/js/example.js"); // Or what else you want to do
    // HERE I'm confident that my webpage is loaded and my js files too.
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, this does not answer the question because I was talking about dynamically adding scripts.