# What JavaScript code can you change at run-time?

Tags: javascript, html

Quote from Wikipedia:

> JavaScript, allow programs to create new code at run-time and execute it using an eval function, but do not allow existing code to be mutated.

Does that include the JS code in event handler attributes and in `href`s with the `javascript:` prefix? Can you change these attributes at run-time with JS code or not?

Can I create a new `<script>` element at run time? If I define a new version of a function in there, what happens? Will the browser prefer my new function to the old one?

If I can’t change an event handler attribute, can I add a new event handler attribute which takes precedence over the old? W.g. an `onmouseover` where the old one is `onclick`? And change the parts in the call somewhat?

Comment: You can just open your dev tools, pick any element and change its attributes.

Comment: This is deep mate!

Comment: Why didn't you first try before asking?

Comment: @Xufox So I can change the attributes of an old script element but not its contents, the js code itself?

Comment: @trincot Experimentation takes a lot of time. I wanted to hear the prevailing js wisdom here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change an event handler attribute. That's part of the DOM, not Javascript. So if you do:

```
document.getElementById("someButton").onclick = someFunction;
```

that will change what happens when you click on the button.

You can also redefine functions, so if the function is called by its name, the new definition will be executed from then on.

But if you pass a function reference, the redefinition has no effect on whatever is using that reference.

As an example, if you do:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFun()">Click Me</button>
```

If you redefine `myFun`, clicking will use the new definition.

If you instead do:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton">Click Me</button>
<script>
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFun);
</script>
```

redefining the function will *not* affect that button. The `myFun` variable is evaluated to get the function object at the time you call `addEventListener()`, and redefining the function doesn't do anything to that object.

You could change the JS to:

```
document.etElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    myFun();
});
```

and then it will look up the function definition every time the anonymous function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can overwrite event handlers and hrefs including JS code by setting the attribute on the html element.

Can create a script element. [document.createElement("script") synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously)