# Get js (node.js) code from html page and run it after load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get js code from somewhere else and run it
But it did not run after loading

Does anyone know how to run?
(Code here)

thanks

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = 'http://localhost/check.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

js page:

```
alert("work?");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.createElement("script") synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously)

Answer (score 0):

You created http server, which listening 80 port? localhost using if local server, if you want to load local file - use path for file (not for server localhost).