# '$ is not defined' on first load

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I'm writing a html plugin for a tool(sonarqube).
In this I need to write code in below fashion by first registering a extension.

While running the code, I'm facing:
`ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

**Code:**

```
window.registerExtension('CustomPlugin/muPlugin', function (options) {

    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    var pluginContainer = document.createElement('div');
    pluginContainer.setAttribute("id", "pluginContainer");
    options.el.appendChild(pluginContainer)
    $("#pluginContainer").load("/static/CustomPlugin/customPluginWebPage.html");  // Facing error on this line.

    return function () {};

});
```

It works when I load the plugin second time, but not the first time.
Any suggestion, how can I make sure jquery is available the first time?

*Thanks you*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: ^I don't think this is a duplicate at all, technically very different compared to the one you mentioned. @zmag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplication of - [document.createElement(“script”) synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously)

**ES5:**

> You can create your  element with an "onload" handler, and that will be called when the script has been loaded and evaluated by the browser.

```js
script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
//Bind a onload handler
script.onload = () => {
  console.log($);
};
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

**EDIT 1:**

**ES6:**

The above is the best solution, unless you're prepared to host jQuery locally then you could use [dynamic import()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import) which runs asynchronously. Support is not great - https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import. Here is [another link](https://tomat.blog/lazy-loading-jquery-with-webpack-only-when-you-need-it-76a8ee144bdd) making use of this. I would only recommend using this where [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/) is used.

```
import('./jquery.min.js').then((jquery) => {
  window.jQuery = jquery;
  window.$ = jquery;
  // The rest of your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeOut()`

```
window.registerExtension('CustomPlugin/muPlugin', function (options) {

script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);

var pluginContainer = document.createElement('div');
pluginContainer.setAttribute("id", "pluginContainer");
options.el.appendChild(pluginContainer);
setTimeout(() => {
  $("#pluginContainer").load("/static/CustomPlugin/customPluginWebPage.html"); 
}, 2000);


return function () {};
});
```