# Getting error when run simple Javascript from Chrome Snippet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Getting syntax error on simple javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
document.write("JavaScript is a simple language for javatpoint learners");  
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe JavaScript is not that simple language after all ..? But definitely JS should not contain HTML tags.

Comment: @Teemu - Of course not. I mean to say my program is simple.

Comment: You  need to remove the script tags - it looks like it expects pure script

Comment: You are right but now in that case if I want to import some JS via SRC before my script, how I can do that if it wont accept < > tags.

Comment: You can create a script element in the current document and set its src to that remote script URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm - any example please? I did look at most of SO questions but still unable to import my external JS from which are here : https://grapesjs.com/docs/getting-started.html#import-the-library

Comment: [document.createElement("script") synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248500)

Comment: Why not use a playground like jsfiddle.net or codepen.io?

Comment: @mplungjan - Because I am trying to drag and drop element on this page : https://grapesjs.com/demo.html , So I think I have to open that page and execute javascript from same chrome tab, else it wont work.