# Wait for turbolinks to load before loading a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables, turbolinks

I've had an issue I couldn't solve in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66807278/script-loading-before-turbolinks-is-ready-datatable-is-not-a-function)

its problem, in short, is that [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) isn't loading until I refresh the page.
so I thought about solving it by adding a `turbolinks:load` event listener to the `<script>` tag, in order to load the CDN after turbolinks loads. Is it possible?

This is my code at the end of my `genes.html.erb`

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
 
});
</script>
```

and I was thinking of something like:

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
 
});
</script>
```

but obviously, a working one.

Console logs for my attempt:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
genes:162 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (genes:162)
    at Object../node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch (turbolinks.js:75)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.js:994)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.js:948)
    at turbolinks.js:872
(anonymous) @ genes:162
./node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch @ turbolinks.js:75
r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad @ turbolinks.js:994
r.pageLoaded @ turbolinks.js:948
(anonymous) @ turbolinks.js:872
```

> Tried [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248500/14489358)'s reply

added this code to my `gene.html.erb`:

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.onload = function() {
    alert("Script loaded and ready");
  };
  script.src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
 
});
</script>
```

but it doesn't work. Despite receiving the alert from `localhost:3000` saying `Script loaded and ready`, DataTables doesn't show -  Console logs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (genes:168)
    at Object../node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch (turbolinks.js:75)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.js:994)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.js:948)
    at turbolinks.js:872
```

I have also tried adding the script to the `application.js` webpacker (same error)

EDIT 4?:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8">
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.onload = function() {
   alert("Script loaded and ready");
 };
 script.async = true;
 script.src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js";

// MODIFIED THE SCRIPT TO ADD IT TO "BODY" INSTEAD, as in the console, the "working" version has it in the body tag
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
 
});
</script>
```

Works and appends the script to `<head>` but DataTables won't load (not a function). I don't know what's the difference between loading it like this, which doesn't work, and this one that does(after a refresh):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

They actually show up in the console in the same place, within the `<body>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not write something like this:

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
})
</script>
```

You have to create an element for the script tag. See this post:
[document.createElement("script") synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously)

Just add

```html
script.async = true;
```

For creating use

```js
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.onload = function() {
   alert("Script loaded and ready");
 };
 script.async = true;
 script.src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js";
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It failed, though. I've updated the post

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work - I'm not really sure why. I guess it might be a specific DataTables issue, so I'll ask there :/ Thank you, really.

Comment: It didn't work in my fiddle. But if I add script.async = true; it worked.

Comment: Maybe I can add an event listener that says script.onLoad instead of tubolinks load?

Comment: I did a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/dxrmnw0g/1/
Just press run and it works.

Comment: I am completely lost here. The fiddle logs "jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function", "@https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:229:17
mightThrow@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js:3557:29
resolve/&lt;/process&lt;@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js:3625:12
", undefined
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#159:17'>159:17</a> TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function" - but now works after a refresh. If I close and reopen, then I get the same error, and solution afterwards

Comment: The fiddle with the onload event works but 1 in 3 times it doesn't load. Most likely works in the next refresh. The latter one hasn't worked so far in 5 refreshes. I don't really understand the reason, though. I'm just trying to be as informative as I can while lacking the knowledge

Comment: Yes I tested it also with the onload event listner. But the same result as before. It works sometimes and sometimes not.